# Auto Increment column do not have index. Column - "value_id", table - "catalog_product_entity_text"

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, setup-upgrade, index

I'm getting the following error after i upgrade magento version to 2.3.5 and try to run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

> Auto Increment column do not have index. Column - "value_id", table -
> "catalog_product_entity_text"

I tried to add an index as follow in catalog_product_entity_text table but still get the same error message.

```
Action  Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
Edit Edit   Drop Drop   value_id    BTREE   Yes No  value_id    1524    A   No
```

Comment: Have you tried to add the autoincrement index?

Comment: i just tried that, but still showing up the same error. Is is possible some kind of cache i need to clean before i run php bin/magento setup:upgrade again?

Comment: is it a open source or commerce edition? and also can you update your question with the result of the query: `show create table catalog_product_entity_text;`

Answer (score 1):

Have you added a constraint to it?
Like:

```
<constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
        <column name="entity_id"/>
</constraint>
```